# Benchmarking Redis latency of blocking commands (e.g. blpop)?

Tags: performance, redis, benchmarking, latency

I know that typical Redis latency is < 1 millisecond, but am wondering about typical times in microseconds / milliseconds for the latency between a `lpush` to an empty list, and a `blpop` returning that was previously blocking it.

I'm not exactly sure about how to measure this, but am also curious about the internals going on, while the [blpop documentation](http://redis.io/commands/blpop) doesn't seem to dive too deep here.  Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have benchmarks, but it helps to understand that latencies are pretty much the time of computer to respond to changes in ports they're listening to (i.e sockets - probably on the order of microseconds), and then of course any networking that may exist in between the redis server and redis client, which is not something redis can affect.